# Como habilitar CORS en Apache

Tags: javascript, apache2, cors

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una consulta **AJAX** a una **API** de terceros la cual es esta "[url_json](https://api.sunat.cloud/ruc/10403322097)" la cual me devuelve una respuesta **JSON**, y esta es mi consulta **AJAX**:

```
var txt_ruc = 10708823967;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url'+txt_ruc,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('ERROR');
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

cuando lo ejecuto me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://url/ruc/10708823967'
>   from origin 'http://otra_url' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

Adicionalmente investigue sobre **CORS cross-origin resource sharing** e implemente lo que se recomendaba en los foros, en **apache2.conf** cambie el dir

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

y en mi **.htaccess** agrege lo siguiente

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Reinicie el **apache** y aun asi tengo el mismo error, por favor me pueden recomendar otro procedimiento?

Comment: ¿Has revisado la documentación de la API?

Comment: Hola, dos cosas: 1) El servidor al que estás tratando de acceder es el que te está bloqueando, no es **tu** servidor Apache, por lo tanto aunque agregues cabeceras a tu solicitud o a la configuración de tu servidor, no lograrás el cometido. 2) has posteado una ruta con datos de alguna persona real. Por favor modifica el código y elimina dicha información. Saludos

Comment: te falta una comilla en `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"`

Comment: @MauricioContreras esa persona soy yo pero si es contra la reglas pongo ceros, es que es la única forma que devuelva un json

Comment: @JackNavaRow Module headers already enabled, ya lo tenia activado pero aun así tengo el error :(

Comment: tienes  un errror en tu .htaccess en un comentario previo te lo comente , arregla eso y debe funcionar

Comment: @IsraelCorreaQuevedo, no es contra las reglas, es simplemente un tema de protección de datos. Está bien, son los tuyos y en cierta forma te pertenecen, pero no deberías tomarlo a la ligera, es un consejo. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras en ese caso pondré nuevamente mis datos, solo para obtener el formato json, porque de lo contrario no devuelve nada, ya tenga una respuesta, quitare estos datos privados.

Comment: por cierto, el virtualhost por defecto de apache2 es si mas no recuerdo `000-default.conf`

Comment: Ya lo resolvi ;)

Comment: @IsraelCorreaQuevedo Agrega tu respuesta por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la pagina a la que deseas acceder no es tuya, osea no puedes habilitar la politica de accesos `CORS policy` para que puedas realizar peticiones a la pagina. Entonces usa técnicas de `spoofing` sobre la pagina.

Puedes Simular el acceso desde un navegador Web con [SELENIUM](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) un api desarrollado en JAVA para Automatización de Test a paginas Web.

Te dejo un link de Youtube para que mires como hacerlo.[Curso Selenium con Java | Básico | Parte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpKur9lw1R0&list=PLgHCrivozIb3OPj61GmIIwXFqPrDI12vJ&index=11)   , básicamente consistirá en que

1. Accedes a la url emulando un Navegador Web
2. Buscas y editar los elementos HTML de la web, si es necesario escribes texto en inputs y emulas acciones de click. Usando los métodos de el [api de selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#learning-the-api)
3. Lees los resultados.
4. Adicional ( para los capchats deberás obtener la imagen, usar un `JOptionPanel` o `JFrame` para ver la imagen e ingresar los texto tu mismo, aunque ya que conoces la ruta que devuelve respuesta en JSON no necesitas el paso 2, solo el 1 y 3 )